# Thread stack trace to string

Tags: java

What is easiest way to convert `java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace()` to string?

There are plenty of methods how to convert `Throwable` to string, but I need to get **stack trace of particular thread object**.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(StackTraceElement ste: Thread.getStackTrace())
    sb.append("\tat ").append(ste).append("\n");
String trace = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons provides exception utilities to assist with this kind of issue. Among these utilities is a method which accepts a Throwable object and returns a String. You should be able to create a `Throwable` object on your thread, passing it to this function, and using the return as needed.

The method I am referring to can be found here: [Apache Commons Exception Utilities - getStackTrace](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29)